# for or while loop in comparing list

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

We want to write a function that recognizes when a list of numbers
can be interpreted  as a `“Yahtzee”` all five numbers in the list must
be the same. Write a function, called `isYahtzee(aList)`, that takes,
as an argument, a list of 5 numbers and returns a `Boolean`. If all five
numbers are the same, it should return `True`, and otherwise, it should
return `False`. For example, `isYahtzee([1,2,3,4,5])` should  return
`False`, and `isYahtzee([1,1,1,1,1])` should return `True`. You must use
either a `“for loop”` or a `“while loop”` in this function when checking
the values in the list.

This is what I have done so far and I keep getting an error!

```
def isYahtzee(aList):
    for i in Range(0,5):
        if i != i+1:
            return false
        else:
            return true

isYahtzee(1,2,3,4,5)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
builtins.TypeError: isYahtzee() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given
```

Comment: So many mistakes in so shot program :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is better:

```
def isYahtzee(aList):
    return len(set(aList)) == 1

>>> isYahtzee([1,1,1,1,1])
True
>>> isYahtzee([1,2,3,4,5])
False
```

Comment: OP said he is required to use a `for` or `while` -- sounds like a homework assignment.

Comment: I think we need to get the CS Profs thinking a little more creatively.

Comment: Actually, a 5-item list is so small that this solution would be slower than a normal for-loop.  Sets are only very efficient when dealing with larger lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
def isYahtzee(aList):
    for i in range(4):
        if aList[i] != aList[i+1]:
            return False
    return True

isYahtzee([1,1,1,1,1])
# True

isYahtzee([1,2,3,4,5])
# False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using `while`, I think the `for` version is easier to implement.

```
def isYahtzee(aList):
    i = 0
    while i < len(aList) - 1:
        if aList[i] != aList[i + 1]:
            return False

        i += 1

    return True
```

Here's the output:

```
>>> isYahtzee([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
False
>>> isYahtzee([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
True
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code:

1. `isYahtzee` is expecting a singe argument (a list), but you are passing in five.  This is what is raising the `TypeError`.
2. `Range` should be lowercase.
3. `true` and `false` should be capitalized.
4. `i` will *never* equal `i+1`.  Thus, the condition of your if-statement will always evaluate to `True`.
5. Your function never checks or even uses the items in `aList`.

---

Here is a version of `isYahtzee` that works:

```
# Declare the function isYahtzee
def isYahtzee(aList):
    # Iterate over the items in aList
    for item in aList:
        # See if the current item is different from the first
        if item != aList[0]:
            # If so, return False because not all items in aList are duplicates
            return False
    # If we get here, return True because all items in aList are duplicates
    return True
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> def isYahtzee(aList):
...     for item in aList:
...         if item != aList[0]:
...             return False
...     return True
...
>>> isYahtzee([1,1,1,1,1])
True
>>> isYahtzee([1,2,3,4,5])
False
>>>
```